# Dependency Injection with StructureMap... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I have a simple MVC3 Web application. I use structureMap as a dependency Injection.

It works fine with my HomeController, but when I go to a second Controller I have thi error:
MissingMethodException : No zero parameters constructor.

I followed every step I found in tutorials...

Thx.

Here's the code :

```
public class HomeController : AuthorizedController
{
    IRepository<User> _repository;

    public HomeController(IRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}


public class AccountController : AuthorizedController
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;

    public AccountController(IRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

And I use this simple injection:

```
For<IRepository<User>>().Use<UserRepository>();
```

Comment: show the code. Especially the `zero parameters constructor`. My bet is, you don't have it, or it isn't accessible (public)

Comment: Of course I dont have it... I am using StructureMap to wire dependencies

Comment: Where is your controller factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u sure it is working with HomeController? if you have error for second controllor then error should be present for HomeController?

Make sure that your base controller AuthorizedController  has a parameterless public constructor

If you do not define a constructor for a class, a parameterless constructor will be created. However, if you define a constructor with parameters, no parameterless constructor will be created.

> ASP.net MVC Controllor Factory -
>   *System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController* needs a parameterless constructor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW : Yes, it is working with HomeController. That is the point I don't understand.

Comment: your issue resolved? or is it still there? could you share your complete code intrested to see how it is working with home controllor?

Comment: Found the Problem. Thanx to all.

Comment: @user1012750 please explain how you resolved your problem, so that the answer is preserved for posterity :) (it's OK to write an answer for your own question on SO).

Comment: I missed a configuration in StructureMap. UserRepository was using an object that was not configured instructuremap.